# Can AD FS 2016 trust OAuth2 access tokens issued by Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b, adfs4.0

Is it possible to configure AD FS 2016 to trust OAuth2 access tokens that are issued by Azure AD? And if AD FS 2016 can't trust Azure AD, then can it trust Azure AD B2C and/or Azure AD B2B?

This would be the scenario:

1. Client gets an OAuth2 access token issued by Azure AD to call API-1.
2. API-1 requests a new token for API-2 from AD FS 2016 in an on-behalf-of flow.
3. AD FS 2016 issues a new access token (because it trusts the token issued by Azure AD).
4. API-1 calls API-2 sending the token issued by AD FS.

I know that AD FS 2016 can be configured to trust a federation partner organization by creating a claims provider trust using SAML, but the two things that I don't know is 1) do claims provider trusts work with OAuth2 access tokens and 2) does a claims provider trust work between Azure AD and AD FS.

Comment: The closest you can come to this scenario is to use a [client credentials grant flow in oAuth with JWT](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudpfe/2017/10/16/oauth-2-0-confidential-clients-and-active-directory-federation-services-on-windows-server-2016/) . AAD can issue a JWT and ADFS can verify it. While this works, I don't think you'll be able to do a seamless handoff from step 1 to steps 2/3.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely define AAD as a claims provider in ADFS. That's been often done when AAD could only issue SAML2.0 tokens and 1.1 were needed (for SP201x for example). Whether ADFS will use that definition to trust JWT tokens from AAD, I don't know. Should be simple enough to try.